# Chrome Extension Popup randomly shrinks to unusable size on browser action icon click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chart.js

I am using react js & chart.js to render some charts in popup.html

It usually looks like this:

[image: Chrome Extension Chart.js]

But, sometimes shrinks down to unusable size like so:

[image: Unusable Chrome extension popup]

This happens randomly and I get no error messages in the console when it does.

### Simplified Code:

```
// App.js
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    token: null
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    chrome.storage.local.get('token', function(result) {
      result && result.token && this.setState({ token: result.token });
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          this.state.token ?
          <LineChart /> :
          <Placeholder />
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

// LineChart.js
class LineChart extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const canvas = document.getElementById('usageChart');
    if (canvas) {
      this.getChartData()
        .then(data => {
          this.chart = new Chart(canvas, {
            type: 'line',
            data,
            options: chartConfig.options
          });
        });
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <canvas id="usageChart" />
    );
  }
}
```

After checking the popup console, all the components were rendered in both cases, just that the popup window shrunk without any errors.

I tried rendering without `chart.js` chart and this issue occurred a lesser number of times but was still there.

Obviously, the best answer would be one to describe the exact underlying cause. But, I can't even understand how to debug this and find the root cause of this issue? Any help in that direction would be great!

Comment: Sounds like https://crbug.com/428044. It should be fixed in Chrome 67 (currently Canary).

Comment: But, I did try adding setTimeout as well in the storage api callback but that too was of no avail :( But, I do agree this seems to be the exact problem I'm facing.

Comment: @wOxxOm I think you're correct. My build might have errored earlier. I tried to click the icon 40-50 times with setTimeout and the issue did not occur this time. If you post this as a solution, I will accept it! Thanks!